# Referencing library inside of library from Android APP Manifest

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I have an app project, which uses a library (referencing the library project, not using a jar). Inside that first library, I want to use another library (Estimate Beacons Library), this time using a jar inside the first library libs folder. To properly use this second library, I need to declare in the manifest the following service:

```
<service android:name="com.estimote.sdk.service.BeaconService"
     android:exported="false"/>
```

I have tried declaring this service in the APP project manifest, but it doesn't get it. The same using the first library project manifest (normal, if I'm not wrong this manifest is ignored by the compiler?).

Any help would be much appreciated. I've been looking for a similar issue but I didn't get lucky.

Edit:

Even with the following configuration it does not work:

- First library has Estimote Beacon SDK (second library) added in lib folder. Also, it has bluetooth permissions and service declared in the manifest.
- APP project has first library (not using jar but referencing the project) and second library in its lib folder. Bluetooth permissions and service is declared in the manifest.

I also created a test app, declaring the service and bluetooth permissions, and adding the library in the lib folder and it worked great, so it is just getting confused when I use my library.

Answer (score 0):

`AndroidManifest.xml` it's just `Application` configuration file, but not `build` file.

If you are using `Gradle` build system, than your libraries dependencies should be specified in `build.grale` and `settings.gradle` files.

Read this [Building Your Android Project with Gradle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html)

Comment: I'm not using Gradle for the libraries dependencies, in fact I don't know what Gradle actually is. I'll take a look.

Comment: Main point isn't in Gradle build system, but in build system in general. If you can't find class from your library in main project (in AndroidManifest.xml for example), then library isn't in project build path and isn't included in project build. Check this http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html if you are using Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The thing is that I'm not referencing the library as for example is showed in "Declaring library components in the manifest file", but using the .jar of the library. Anyway, I should be able to find a class from the library, but for any unknown reason to me it does not find it (for the project that I want, for an empty and simple project it works).

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling manifest merging in the project.properties file:

```
manifestmerger.enabled=true
```

Also check your generated manifest in the bin directory after you build your project, and make sure the service definition is there.

This is the approach that works for the [Android Beacon Library,](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/configure.html) and I have used it to make other libraries dependent upon it.

Ultimately, though, it is true that Android Studio provides more flexible tools to do this.

Comment: I tried that but no luck. I check the app bin manifest and the service definition is definitely there...it is really weird. Check my last edit please.